# Program runs in visual studio but release executable crashes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file, exe, file-handling

I have tracked it down to when I am writing to a txt file. I've checked that it's open and it writes a line to the file before it crashes.

The VS2012 external debugger throws me this `Unhandled exception at 0x77112D24 (ntdll.dll) in DTC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x10000000` and points me to this function `virtual __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL ~basic_filebuf()` inside of the fstream header.

```
void main()
{
    vector<string> fileNames;
    vector<time_t> fileTimes;

    CImg<unsigned char> image("Image.bmp");

    ofstream out("Result_Data.txt",ios::out|ios::app);
    if(!out.is_open())
    {
        cout<<"File Not Opened!\n";
    }
    unsigned long originalSize = my_image_functions::getFileSize("Image.bmp");
    time_t before = 0, after = 0;

    before=clock();
    my_image_functions::compressDualLevelBTC(image,"dualBTC_2_8.dtc",2,8);
    after = clock();

    fileTimes.push_back(after-before);
    fileNames.push_back("dualBTC_2_8.dtc");

    //...
    /* Several of these segments*/
    //...


    before=clock();
    my_image_functions::compressDualLevelBTC(image,"dualBTC_32_64.dtc",32,64);
    after = clock();

    fileTimes.push_back(after-before);
    fileNames.push_back("dualBTC_32_64.dtc");

    while(!fileNames.empty() && !fileTimes.empty())
    {
        out<< fileNames.back() <<";"<< fileTimes.back() <<";"<< my_image_functions::getFileSize(fileNames.back()) << ";" << ((float) originalSize)/my_image_functions::getFileSize(fileNames.back()) << endl;
        fileNames.pop_back();
        fileTimes.pop_back();
        if(!out.is_open())
        {
            cout<<"File Not Opened!\n";
        }
    }
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: Could you produce the smallest sample of code that reproduces your error and post it?

Comment: I don't know what's causing this to happen to reproduce it at a smaller scale, but this is basically the code.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is that you are missing a needed dll when running the release version.

Run Dependency Walker on the executable: http://dependencywalker.com/

Answer (score 0):

You seem to check if the file is open or not. If it is not, you print the message "Not open" but carry on anyway?

```
ofstream out("Result_Data.txt",ios::out|ios::app);
if(!out.is_open())
{
    cout<<"File Not Opened!\n";
}
```

Comment: I was just trying to track down what was happening, this was just thrown in there to do that.